# Flink ProcessFunction example error

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to go through the Flink docs and understand a few different functionalities and ran into a problem when going through the ProcessFunction documentation.  I am trying to run through this example:

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/process_function.html#example

and I am having a problem with this function:

```
class TimeoutStateFunction extends ProcessFunction[(ObjectNode), (String, Long)] {
  lazy val state : ValueState[CountWithTimestamp] =  getRuntimeContext
    .getState(new ValueStateDescriptor[CountWithTimestamp]("myState", classOf[CountWithTimestamp]))
  //Other Stuff After
}
```

It seems to be that this code cannot work as `getRuntimeContext` does not exist in this scope.  `getRuntimeContext` seems to be apart of the `AbstractRichFunction` class and `ProcessFunction` extends `Function` not `AbstractRichFunction`.  Am I missing something in this example, or is the code here broken?  Is there any suggestions on how to get similar functioning code to work?

Comment: which version of Flink are you using? In Flink 1.3.x (the version to which the documentation link points), `ProcessFunction` extends `AbstractRichFunction` (see [Github](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/5aa93a270a87b5a965e5c37c5c8bd6e6208b09b7/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/ProcessFunction.java)).

Comment: Sorry, yup, that was my problem.  I was using 1.2.x.  Originally I was looking at https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/stream/process_function.html which also shows ```ProcessFunction``` for Scala, but their Java example is using ```RichProcessFunction```, which works in Scala as well.